# Formatando Data e Hora em um DataGrid

Tags: c#, data, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Estou criando uma aplicação onde retorna alguns dados do banco de dados para um DataGrid.

Acontece que o sistema retorna no formato MM/dd/yyyy e eu gostaria que retornasse em nosso formato: **dd/MM/yyyy**.

Já tentei inserir na tag do Xaml o código abaixo:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGridListaNum" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,129,10,0" AlternationCount="2" RowBackground="LightBlue" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding numero}" Header="Número" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial Black" Width="84"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding assunto}" Header="Assunto" FontSize="17" Width="750"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding data, ConverterCulture='pt-BR', StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}}" Header="Data" FontSize="17" Width="140"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Mas continua retornando no mesmo formato do sistema.

**Uma forma que encontrei foi a seguinte.**

Eu mudei o próprio **SELECT** da pesquisa na conexão com o MySql :

```
 public class CmdNumeradores
    { 
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        Conexao con = new Conexao();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();        

        public int NumeroCadastradoComSucesso;       

        public DataTable Numeradores(int tipo)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select numero, assunto, date_format(data, '%d-%m-%y') as data from numerador where tipo = @tipo";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", tipo);                                          
            cmd.Connection = con.Conectar();        
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());                 
            con.Desconectar();
            
            return dt;            
        }
```

Se alguém puder indicar outras formas de fazer essa alteração, como, por exemplo, no XAML.

**Obs:** A **Conexao** é a Classe que leva a String de conexão com o BD MySql.

```
public class Conexao
    {       

        MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
        
        public Conexao()
        {
            conexao.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=gerenciajd;UID=root;PASSWORD=12345;Allow Zero Datetime=True";        
        }

        public MySqlConnection Conectar()
        {
            if(conexao.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conexao.Open();
            }
            return conexao;
        }

        public void Desconectar()
        {
            if (conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eu queria ver o DataGrid pois me interessam essas propriedades `<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="????" AutoGeneratingColumn="??" />`

Comment: Desculpa, já estou adicionando.

Answer (score 0):

Se `data` é um DateTime, você pode simplesmente usar:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding data, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"/>
```

Se `data` **não** é um `DateTime` (talvez seja um `string`?), ai você pode pensar em montar um [Converter](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), que fará o trabalho de transformar "seja lá o que for" no formato que precisa.